# splitting by comma in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data  in dataframe

```
           From                        To
          [time]                       clock time
          [year]                       twelvemonth, yr
          [people]                     None
          [way]                        means, agency
          [lily]                       flower
          [man]                        homo, human being, human
          [man]                        adult male, male
          [case]                       instance, example
          [case]                       lawsuit, suit, cause, causa
          [case]                       display case, showcase, vitrine
```

What i want is  spliting it from "," in **TO** Column and creating seperate row for each entry so the expected outout will be

```
               From                        To
              [time]                       clock time
              [year]                       twelvemonth
              [year]                       yr
              [people]                     None
              [way]                        means
              [way]                        agency
              [lily]                       flower
              [man]                        homo
              [man]                        human being
              [man]                        human
              [man]                        adult male
              [man]                        male
              [case]                       instance
              [case]                       example
              [case]                       lawsuit
              [case]                       suit
              [case]                       cause
              [case]                       causa                              
              [case]                       display case
              [case]                       showcase
              [case]                       vitrine
```

My data is in Dataframe  format
I have tried this  but this does not help

```
b = pd.concat([pd.Series(row['From'], row['To'].split(','))
               for _, row in df.iterrows()]).reset_index()
```

Can any one help doing this?

Comment: tried explode it doesnot helps so added it as new question @jezrael

Comment: Give me a sec, I add more dupes.

Comment: i went through all those before adding the questions , but ws not able to solve it so i have added it. please understand

Comment: Hmm, so maybe some specific problem.

Comment: I add another dupe, can you check it?

Comment: @jezrael  Thanks , one of the solution did worked from these thanks alot